# Fireabase Realtime Database client requests have expired, I have re enabled them, but still entries are not created in the db?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android app for my degree and I am using Firebase Realtime Database, the app is going to be something similar to spotify, but on a smaller scale. I was forced to take a longer break and my client requests from the Database have been automatically disabled (the 30 day limit by default).
I've changed the rules to be "true" for both read and write(for the purpose of making it work, not secure, I will change them appropriately). I also attached some screenshots and code snippets to help. I checked other stack questions and they didnt help, the only solution I see right now is making another project so basically reinitializing the whole thing withing a new Firebase project.

```
private void registerUser(){
    final String email = emailField.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = usernameField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmPass = confirmPasswordField.getText().toString().trim();

    if(username.isEmpty()){
        usernameField.setError("Username is required");
        usernameField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(email.isEmpty()){
        emailField.setError("Email is required");
        emailField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.isEmpty()){
        passwordField.setError("Password is required");
        passwordField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        emailField.setError("Please provide valid email");
        emailField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.length() < 6){
        passwordField.setError("Password length should be at least 6 characters");
        passwordField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(!password.equals(confirmPass)){
        confirmPasswordField.setError("Passwords do not match");
        confirmPasswordField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        User user = new User(username, email);

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User has registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration has failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This is where I register my user to the Realtime Database. They do show up in the authentication tab and I can log in with them, but they do not in the database.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true",
    }
  }
}
```

These are the rules that I am using right now with the purpose of getting to the bottom of this issue that I am having right now, I am planning to change them so that the users can only write data that belongs to them.

Basically my question boild down to, if my client requests have expired, what can I do to re enable them so that I can have entries in my Realtime DB again? [This is the DB right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoSii.png)

Comment: If you try to log in the else part, `Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());`, is there something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: "client requests have expired" What does this mean? What action does your code take, and what result do you get?

Comment: hey there, the client requests have expired refers to firebase having a 30 day limit on creation of the realtime database in testing mode. after those 30 days the read and write are set to false. I figured out the issue and got it working, basically I used " " when declaring the values for read and write. While they work for expressions, they do not when you just want to set them as just true or false. Feel free to close the question/mark it as answered